# Python: binary conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, flags

I have multiple conditions, like this:

```
if condition:
  flag1 = True
flag2 = testfunc()
flag3 = bool(variable)
if not flag1 and not flag2 and not flag3:
  do0
elif flag1 and flag2:
  do1
elif flag2 and flag3:
  do2
```

Can I change it to something like this:

```
flags = 0
if condition:
  flags += 1
if testfunc():
  flags += 2
if bool(variable):
  flags += 4
if flags == 0:
  do0
elif flags == 3:
  do1
elif flags == 6:
  do2
```

As you can understand there can be values 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... for conditions. Is it possible to do something like this in Python? Thanks!

**UPDATE**. This is something like conditions in `re` and `PyQt4` modules (where you can set something like `re.UNICODE` | `re.DOTALL`).

Example from `re` module:

```
DOTALL = 16
I = 2
IGNORECASE = 2
L = 4
LOCALE = 4
M = 8
MULTILINE = 8
S = 16
U = 32
UNICODE = 32
VERBOSE = 64
X = 64
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to do this - your code should run fine as is (given variables and functions are declared).

Is it a good idea? Not really - it's much less obvious when reading what you mean. Readability comes first.

If your problem is with the lots of `and`s, then you can clean it up in other ways:

```
if not any(condition, flag2, variable):
```

Using `any()` and `all()` can often help you simplify things down.

Comment: Wow, it seems to be very useful. I will take it into service!

Comment: However creators of PyQt4 and re are seemed to use the way I ask. Just for education it will be useful to understand how to get something like this. Did they use bits for this?

Comment: @ghostmansd These are [bitwise operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) - I would presume that these are used more for consistency with underlying C libraries, and would argue against writing pure-python code that worked in the same way.